# PowerShell array count not zero

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to understand why this array `count` is not resulting in `0`

```
@($null).Count
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Because that's an array with one item in it (`$null`). It's not empty. `@().Count` returns zero.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Nice. Please consider putting in an answer so we can get it out of the unanswered queue, and upvote etc.

Comment: Done, with a bit of elaboration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@($null)` is an array with a single `$null` element (hence the `Count` property is `1`). Likewise `@($null,$null).Count` is `2`, and `@().Count` is `0`. Keep in mind that `@($null)` emits `$null` to the pipeline, so the `Count` property returned from `@($null) | Measure-Object` will be `0`.